# Change the name of TaggerProvider and the code fails to work

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I cloned https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples, the project  Intra-text_Adornment/C# works perfectly.

Then I changed the name of `ColorAdornmentTaggerProvider` to `CCAdornmentTaggerProvider`, then run the project. The extension doesn't work any more.

My change is https://github.com/gqqnbig/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/commit/575d74300fc22b61d694f0c7f6a05e71c7fd79fe

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find another way to fix it. I have to uninstall my extension from the experimental instance, or delete folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_5c91ae55Exp\Extensions`.

My guess is that since ColorAdornmentTaggerProvider has the Export attribute, when VS is installing the extension, VS remembers the class name, `ContentType`, `TagType`, and sort of things. When I rename the class to `CCAdornmentTaggerProvider`, the extension didn't get reinstalled, the experimental instance is still looking for `ColorAdornmentTaggerProvider`, but cannot find it.

Comment: Please consider marking this as answer if it do work. Thanks for your sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix it?

When you changed the name of `ColorAdornmentTaggerProvider` to `CCAdornmentTaggerProvider`, you need to change all Color-related class to CC-related ones to make the extension work.

Trying renaming the Class name in solution explorer and choose `OK` when you get this messagebox to rename all `Colorxxx` code elements to `CCxxx`.

[image]

After renaming the class name, the structure should be similar to this:

[image]

Then you can get the extension work after fixing the compile errors if exist.

Comment: Is MEF convention based, that tag, tagger, tagger providers and sort of things must share the same prefix?

Comment: @Gqqnbig I haven't found any document to confirm this, but it do work and you can easily check this (I can reproduce the same issue like your original one and resolve it in this way) So this might be a workaround.